# The type or namespace name 'Parse' does not exist in the namespace 'Enum'

Tags: c#, enums

I have System in my namespace, what am I missing? I am brand new to C# and am following a course on Udemy and following a book titled C#8.0 and .NET Core 3.0 - any other materials that people recommend would be really useful.

The problem is arising from Enum.Parse

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Enum
{
    public enum ShippingMethod
    {
        RegularMail = 1,
        Registered = 2,
        Express = 3
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var method = ShippingMethod.Express;
            Console.WriteLine((int)method);

            var methodId = 3;
            Console.WriteLine((ShippingMethod)methodId);

            Console.WriteLine(method.ToString());

            //Here we take a string and convert it a enum
            var methodName = "Express";
            //We will have to "parse" the string to a different type
            var shippingMethod = (ShippingMethod)Enum.Parse(typeof(ShippingMethod), methodName);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I found exactly the same thing Enum.Parse compiled fine yesterday. Today it gives an error(?)

Answer (score 1):

I had to change it to System.Enum.Parse  - odd, because I have using System; in the file.

Answer (score 1):

```
namespace Enum_1
{
public enum ShippingMethod
{
    RegularMail = 1,
    Registered = 2,
    Express = 3
}
```

Change the namespace Enum, something like Enum_1

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31714274)

Answer (score 0):

You have to check your namespace to not be {{Your solution name}}.Enum

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer